# subprocess как найти текст в выводе?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin python3

import subprocess
a = '/dev/sda1'
s = subprocess.call(["df", "-l"])
if a in str(s):
    print('YES')
```

То что хотелось бы найти: /dev/sda1       8,8G  5,5G  2,9G  66% /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить проценты занятости для заданной файловой системы, используя  [GNU `df` утилиту](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/df-invocation.html#df-invocation):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['df', '/dev/sda1', '--output=pcent'])
print(output.splitlines()[-1].decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
#!/usr/bin python3

import subprocess
a = '/dev/sda1'
res = subprocess.run(["df", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lines = res.stdout.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
for line in lines:
    l = line.split()
    if l[0] == a:
        break
print(l)
```

Вывод у меня:

```
['/dev/sda1', '976283900', '1473164', '974810736', '1%', '/mmedia']
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, для линии это будет работать. На самом деле хотел из этой линии, точнее из радела /dev/sda1 брать только процент (%) сколько места занята в разделе.
Т.е. хотел получать не всю строку а 70%  к примеру.

Comment: Тут проще всего брать элемент списка с индексом 4. Хотя можно было и регулярными выражениями сделать, но это только всё усложнит